# Changing InternalBufferSize on FileSystemWatcher for a network path

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I've got a FileSystemWatcher in a windows service that I need to make the InternalBufferSize bigger on. I've set it to a multiple of 4096 (currently 20 * 4096). If I'm monitoring a local drive, I have no problems and everything works fine.

If I change the directory being monitored to a unc path, I get a 'The parameter is incorrect' error message, and no changes are picked up by the watcher.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: The buffer size limit is an implementation detail for the file system that you use.  If it is an UNC path then you may well run into something troublesome, like a cheap NAS device that boots Linux.  Tends to fall into the "you get what you paid for" bracket.  Get another one or make your code smarter by dumping the notifications into a thread-safe queue as quickly as possible.

Comment: Its a multitiered setup, very expensive and fast. I would however, not put it past our network guys to have put the wrong settings on it. I'll check up on when the main support guy is back in the office.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation of the underlying unmanaged function [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365465):

> `ReadDirectoryChangesW` fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when the
>   buffer length is greater than 64 KB and the application is monitoring
>   a directory over the network. This is due to a packet size limitation
>   with the underlying file sharing protocols.

Your buffer is 80 KB and exceeds this limit. See if the maximum (64 KB) will do for your purposes. If not, you'll have to work around it some other way -- increasing the buffer size is out, apparently.